# Changing characters in different positions (Example:at the end of the word)

Tags: php

so I have a problem and I can't find a way to do it.

So I have this string:

```
username,artur,aadasdd,artur12
```

And I would like to convert it to something like that:

```
username='artur',aadasdd='artur12'
```

This is just a example I have a big var with those information's.
And I can't use str_split function because every table have different length 
(username is a table name same as aadasdd and artur, artur12 are values).

Anybody have a idea?

Comment: Is the string format always in pairs : name,value,name,value...? And is the separator always comma?

Comment: Yes exactly, always comma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the string format is always "name,value,name,value,...", and if the separator is always comma, you can use "explode", example:

```
<?php

$my_var = "username,artur,aadasdd,artur12";
$my_array = explode( "," , $my_var );

for ( $i = 0; $i < count( $my_array ); $i++ )
{ echo $my_array[ $i ] . "=" .
       "'" . $my_array[ $i+1 ] . "',";
  $i++;
}
?>
```

This code would display:

```
username='artur',aadasdd='artur12',
```

Comment: Thank you very much. How can I push all of the results into one variable? Example echo $newResult?

Comment: Instead of "echo $my_array . . " do "$newResult = $my_array . . .".